# Getting attribute from an xml tag with xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml file, I use the xpath `/content` which returns the following line:

```
<content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

How can I get the type 'nil'? I am trying to write a test which will check if the content is empty, if there is no conten it will say nil="true" otherwise it will give the type e.g. xsi:type="String">true

I've tried //content[@xsi] and //content/xsi but still can't limit it down to just the part I want.

I could just get a substring but I think there must be a way to do it with xpath.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet:

```
<content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

there is a *namespace*. Although it does not apply to the element `content`, it does apply to the attribute `nil`. It is an attribute from the XML Schema specification, by the way.

To find an attribute that is in a namespace you either

- cleanly register this namespace in your application and *prefix* the attribute in any XPath expression
- ignore all namespaces in path expressions

You did not show any code, so I find it hard to comment on the first option. The second option means a path expression like

```
//content[@*[local-name() = 'nil'] = 'true']
```

will select `content` elements where the `xsi:nil` attribute value is "true".